# Can't run or access xamarin xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Is there wrong with my set up or version?

I was expecting to run the application with the Android part of the namespace being accessible but got error:
**The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform'(are you missing an assembly reference?)**

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFo3e.png)

[The error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLCJu.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post code and error messages as images and always describe the problem as best as you can: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1. Update the Xamarin.Forms nuget to the latest version.
2. Delete the obj/ bin folders, then restart VS, and rebuild it.